# Best swappiness for 4GB RAM

Tags: ram, swap

I have problems that games on my ***laptop***(CS:GO) take a very long time to load and don't run smoothly, although it used to run smoothly on windows os. (I have converted to ubuntu just a week ago!!)

After some research, I found out that this may be caused by swappiness value. I tried playing around with values on my own but that made it even worse.

By the way, I only have 4GB of RAM and I have set my swap file to 4GB as well.

Comment: Are they the same games in Windows and Ubuntu? Do you have configured drivers for your graphics card? It may not be related to swap. I myself use swappiness of 5 on my laptop with 4GB RAM, so that it would try to use the RAM aggressively.

Comment: Try a vm.swappiness=80

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi vm.swappiness=5 is TOTALLY wrong for 4G RAM.

Comment: @haynnema I take care not to open too many browser tabs or not to open too many memory hungry softwares simultaneously. Having large swappiness would make the computer sluggish as I don't have an SSD. Is that a bad idea? Of course, I want to know your opinion

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi (you misspelled my username) Anyway... with only 4G RAM, you **want** it to swap when necessary. vm.swappiness=5 won't allow that for the most part, and in fact, may cause **more** lockups with full memory. I'd also set vm.swappiness=80 in your case, and get to use more of your memory, with the slight speed penalty.

Comment: guys i didnt get or understand must of what you said....can you please be more clear

Comment: i have the latest nvidea 455 properiety drivers by the way

Comment: Increasing swap on older machines, with spinning drives, puts all those r/w on another mechanical device rather than the solid state one it was operating on. meaning more heat, more disk i/o operations..performance hits. Swap was essential decades ago, now it is more of a convenience. The main objective today is to swap out inactive processes so your memory is free for use. But if you are conscious of it, like @ArchismanPanigrahi, his method functions just as well. On my machine swap is there for emergency-only 1G. and If I see it used, I empty it. With that said I have 48G of ram so it's rare

Comment: @WU-TANG Did you read that OP was using HDD vs SSD? On your computer, with 48G RAM, why not set the swap at 2-4G, and stop having to manually empty it? You could also set your vm.swappiness=10 and see how that goes.

Comment: @heynnema  as for my case, there is no benefit for me using swap outside of an emergency... like me turning on a 4th VM and consuming 6 gigs by mistake and exceeding RAM. So now I have a VM in swap, which is horrible... yes I am going to shut that down and empty the swap so that whatever else entered, returns to RAM. Having inactive processes in swap doesn't help that situation (for me). But I do think any strategy should be hardware and application/purpose centric, to your point, you are right the OP did not mention SSD vs HDD (that was Archisman Panigrahi)... my confusion.

Comment: @WU-TANG re: *"Having inactive processes in swap"*... it's not inactive **processes** in swap... it's inactive recently used **pages** in swap. Even if you have lots of memory, and vm.swappiness=10, enough swap is still a good thing to have. In your case, 1G swap is too small.

Comment: @heynnema "still a good thing to have" is not a good reason... "1G swap is too small" is not a good nor valid answer... too small for what? too small to be never used? I have a machine that hasn't used swap since Dec.(christmas upgrade!!) Would I not be wasting 4G of hard drive space on swap? If there is enough memory, and "MY" swap is set to be used when absolutely needed (swappiness=0) then it could end up that 100M could technically have been "enough". Again, hardware, purpose, activities... there is no "wrong", there is optimization. Swap is a VERY VERY OLD concept, technology has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re: "*After some research, I found out that this may be caused by swappiness value. I tried playing around with values on my own but that made it even worse*."

With 4G RAM and 4G swap, I'd recommend setting vm.swappiness=80.

In `terminal`...

`sudo cp /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.conf.BAK` # backup the file

`sudo pico /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Add this at the end of the file...

```
# adjust swap vs ram ratio, default=60
vm.swappiness=80
```

Save the file and quit the editor.

`sudo sysctl -p` # use the new values

**Note**: You may be required to add additional memory to your computer. Make sure to configure them as equal size/type SODIMMs.

Comment: the game is now running smoothly but the  loading time increased dramatically !!

Comment: @shugran_04 setting vm.swappiness really shouldn't effect loading time. Too little memory and a slow HDD could. Maybe you don't fully understand how swap (and vm.swappiness) works. Google it if you wish. Try checking the game loading time immediately after a reboot.

Comment: the game loads a bit faster after reboot. maybe you are right I think 4gb isn't enough.

Comment: @shugran_04 You could also get a SSD (along with that extra memory) :-)